# move_uploaded_file is not working i am using cakephp3.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to upload image with the using of CakePhp3.0. Below is the code which one I am using to upload image but it is not working.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($this->data['Document']['submittedfile']['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT.'img/profile_img/' . $this->data['Document']['submittedfile']['name'])){
    echo "file uploaded";
} else {
    echo "file not uploaded";
}
```

I set 777 permission .

Answer (score 2):

At first see the following post

[cakePHP 3.0 uploading images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648335/cakephp-3-0-uploading-images)

also look [Uploading Files and Images with CakePHP](http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/uploading_files_and_images_with_cakephp)

I think the above post will be helpful.