# Cakephp send mail

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.4

I am using cakephp2.4.5 & I am completely new to cakephp can any one please help me how to write a form in cakephp and how to send a mail

[image]

I have this form, when user fill E-mail and Message box and hit on send a mail should sent with the above information. I didn't have any idea how to write even a from please help me

Crated view

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Feedback', array('action' => 'sendmail')); ?>
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('mail',array('label' => false,'class'=>'form__in form__in--text form-control','placeholder'=>__('E-mail'),'div'=>false));?>
 <?php echo $this->Form->textarea('message',array('label' => false,'class'=>'form__in form__in--textarea form-control','placeholder'=>__('Message'),'div'=>false));?>
 <?php echo $this->Form->end(array('label' => 'Send', 'class' => 'form__submit', )); ?>
```

Controller file

```
<?php
//App::uses('CakeTime', 'Utility');
class FeedbacksController extends AppController {

public function sendmail()
{ 

}


}
```

Comment: Follow this link: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your controller file.

```
 public function sendmail()
 { 
    if ($this->request->is('post')) 
    {
      if ($this->Feedback->save($this->request->data)) //Save form data before sending mail
      {
        //Your Form's fields
        $name = $this->data['Feedback']['name'];
        $email = $this->data['Feedback']['email'];
        $subject = $this->data['Feedback']['subject'];
        $msg = $this->data['Feedback']['message'];
        $to = "recipient@gmail.com";
        $from = $email;
        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From:' .$from. " ".'<'.$from.'>'."\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Reply-To:'.$from. "\r\n";
        $sent_message = mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers); //Send mail

      }
      else
      {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The contact could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'default',array('class'=>'errors'));
      }
    }

 }
```

You can see my answer also for writing form in cake php
[Uploading image in cakephp and storing it's path in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465028/uploading-image-in-cakephp-and-storing-its-path-in-database/30476245#30476245)

Comment: How do I validate this form.?

Comment: Better to use CakeEmail class for sending emails http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html